# How to dynamically set a limited range for my dates via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML that generates once the DOM is ready..

```
<div class="session-block mdatepicker">

<label>Next Appointment Date</label>

<select class="mdropdown" name="mde502fbrp__40[]" id="mdays">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="13">13</option>
<option value="14">14</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
<option value="17">17</option>
<option value="18">18</option>
<option value="19">19</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="21">21</option>
<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="23">23</option>
<option value="24">24</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="26">26</option>
<option value="27">27</option>
<option value="28">28</option>
<option value="29">29</option>
<option value="30" selected="selected">30</option>
<option value="31">31</option>
</select>

<select class="mdropdown" name="mde502fbrp__40[]" id="mmonths">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="1">January</option>
<option value="2">February</option>
<option value="3">March</option>
<option value="4" selected="selected">April</option>
<option value="5">May</option>
<option value="6">June</option>
<option value="7">July</option>
<option value="8">August</option>
<option value="9">September</option>
<option value="10">October</option>
<option value="11">November</option>
<option value="12">December</option>
</select>

<select class="mdropdown" name="mde502fbrp__40[]" id="myears">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="2013" selected="selected">2013</option>
</select>

</div>
```

My goal is to limit the months so that only the next 2 months appear in the dropdown.  So I was able to do that with some jQuery like this...

```
$('#mmonths option').each(function() {
  var mvalues = parseInt($(this).val());
  if(mvalues > 5) { 
   $(this).remove();
  }
});
```

So with that function, I'm pretty much removing any month after May, and that is cool.

But I don't want go back to this code every month, just to make adjustments on my mvalues variable.  Instead I want it know what the current date is X and always show only 2 months ahead of the current date, no matter if its June, July, August, etc...

When it gets to November, I would like to show December and January, etc..

But I am not sure where or how to learn how to do this...

Any advice would be great!

Comment: why don't you use [jquery ui datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Comment: that looks cool and I think I would, but the code I'm showing you is built into a module (Form Builder) for CMS Made Simple, and its called the date picker.  I need the Form Builder to complete the rest of my task.  This issue I have is just a 3rd of what I am trying to overcome.

Comment: one clarification, since today is april, you have to show from Jan to Jun in the month dropdown is it correct

Comment: Yes you are correct...but now that I think about it...who sets appointments in the past?  I think the end goal is still the same..to set 2 upcoming months as a drop down option.  Thanks for looking out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this --

```
var today_date = new Date();
var currentMonth = today_date.getMonth();

$('#mmonths option').each(function() {
  var mvalues = parseInt($(this).val());
  if(mvalues > currentMonth + 3 || mvalues <= currentMonth) { 
   $(this).remove();
  }
});
```

`.getMonth()` will return month but it returns between 0 - 11 and not 1-12. So need to add that one and make it 3 for next two months. This also avoid selecting previous months as well if you want to.

See [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Hywwk/)

Comment: That looks very easy to understand, thank you much @SachinG, I will try it out!

Answer (score 1):

create a new date object `new Date()` and get month `getMonth()` this will give you current month...

try thiss

```
$('#mmonths option').each(function() {
  var mvalues = parseInt($(this).val());
  var d = new Date(),m = d.getMonth();
  if(mvalues > parseInt(m + 2)) { 
   $(this).remove();
  }
});
```

however,

> When it gets to November, I would like to show December and January, etc..

i don't think your code is doing that now... since your are just removing the months that is greater that current date and doing nothing with previous months..

so , this does not hide the other months when you reach november or december...atleast this will get you moving since you have some idea about current date

Comment: yes, it does get me moving and I appreciate that @bipen!  Thank you very much for your example!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$('#mmonths option').filter(function() {
    var current_month = (new Date).getMonth();
    var month = parseInt($(this).val(), 10) - 1;
    var diff = month - (current_month + 1) % 12;

    if (diff < 0) {
        diff += 12;
    }

    return diff >= 2;
}).remove();
```

Although this will place December after January in the case of November.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option

Remove all items in the months select element

```
<select class="mdropdown" name="mde502fbrp__40[]" id="mmonths">
</select>
```

Then use the following JavaScript

```
 var months = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",
                "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];

var d = new Date, 
    from = d.getMonth(), 
    to = from + 3,
    select = document.getElementById("mmonths");

for( var i = from; i < to; i++ ) {

    var _m = i % 12; // if month more than 11 then use remainder
    select.appendChild( new Option( months[ _m ], _m ) );

}
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8CUCB/1/)